# Improve performance (timeout error)

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, performance

**Problem**

You are given a set `S = {1,2,3...N}`. Find two integers `A` and `B`  from the set `S` such that the value of  `&`  is the maximum possible and less than the given integer `K`. In this case, `&` represents the operator bitwise AND.

```
2 <= N <= 10^3
2 <= K <= N
```

**Solution**

```
#Brute force
testCases = int(raw_input())
while testCases > 0:
    n_k = raw_input().split()
    n = range(1, int(n_k[0]) + 1) #THIS IS THE RANGE S
    k = int(n_k[1])
    max_pair = -1
    for x in n[:len(n)-1]:
        for y in n[x:]:
            x_y = x & y
            if( x_y < k):
                max_pair = max(max_pair, x_y)
print max_pair
testCases -= 1
```

**Question**

I have steamed over how to improve this code but I can't arrive at an answer. I get a timeout error when N is very long. Could anyone point me in the right direction to figure out how to improve this code? I can't think of a way to shorten the loops, what criteria could I possibly use? A bitwise **&** makes you lose information, it's not like there's a reversible method for it (like when you add, to get it back you subtract...).

My trail of thought:

- (A & B) < K
- I know A from the first loop, how can I make the second loop iterate less?
- (A & B) = 1...(k-1)
- How in the world can I move B to the other side of the equation so I can start discarding numbers faster in the second loop?

**EDIT:  Solutions**

I am definitely laughing at this one. Thanks to user @ead I learned there's a faster interpreter for Python, so instead of choosing "Python 2" I chose "Pypy 2"... all test cases passed freaking quickly and no time out erros. I've been steaming my brains for days... I can't believe it, hahahaha.

For the LOLs I went ahead and translated the code to use JS (Node.js) and low and behold... not timeout erros there. If anyone wants the code in JS, here it is.

```
function processData(input) {
    var data = input.split("\n");
    var testCases = parseInt(data[0]);
    var n_k, n, k, max_pair;
    for(let index=1; index<data.length; ++index){
        n_k = data[index].split(" ");
        n = getSet( parseInt(n_k[0]) ),
        k = parseInt(n_k[1]);
        max_pair = 0;
        n.forEach(function(a){
            for(let i=a; i<n.length; ++i){
                let a_b = a & n[i];
                if(a_b < k)
                    max_pair = Math.max(max_pair, a_b);
            }
        });
        console.log(max_pair);
    }
}

function getSet(n){
    var n_set = [];
    for(let index=1; index<=n; ++index)
        n_set.push(index);
    return n_set;
}
```

Comment: How big can testCases be?

Comment: It's at the top: 2 <= N <= 10^3

Comment: The easiest way to improve performance would be to submit the solution as a pypy solution:)

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: I meant variable testCases, not the size of the set

Comment: testCases is not the problem, my problem is the set, when the set is close to 10^3 , my code takes too long and times out because my loops are looking into options I have not managed to discard sooner.

Comment: Pypy is a python Interpreter which is about 5 times faster for this type of problem. Many competitive programming problems are not ment to be solved with cpython. Sometimes you can choose the language for your submission-choose pypy!

Comment: I will be damned...just tried it, freaking worked. What the heck?

Comment: Since x & y <= x and x & y <= y there is no need to consider x or y that are smaller than the maximum so far.

Comment: @dmuir I don't quite understand. Could you explain it in another way? The maximum is neither x nor y, it's a number K.

Comment: Written in c/c++ your solution would not need more than 0.01 seconds per iteration of the while-loop. I think there is nothing there but the slow python.

Comment: Thank you very much @ead , I definitely learned something today. I need to get into C++ so things like this don't give me a headache for days. Beautiful.

Comment: Actually, for competitive programming it is an advantage to be good with python and c++. Somethings are really easier with python (big integer for example) but sometimes you just need all speed you can get!

Comment: Suppose you have found a value for max_pair. Then there is no point testing values of x or y that less than max_pair because x & y <= min(x,y) <= max_pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is nothing special, just the fact that the CPython is quite slow for integer operations. Written in C/C++ your program will be really fast and don't need more than 0.01 sec per while-loop.

In the competing programming a lot of problems are never meant to be solved with CPython but with [PyPy](https://pypy.org/), which has a faster integer-arithmetic and a git-compiler but otherwise a python interpreter just as CPython.

So just choose PyPy in contests, whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks for this, will definitely choose Pypy from now on. Although seems a bit unfair if one is not aware of this. I'm going to solve it in JS (Node) now, see what happens. :)

Comment: Choice of algorithm is more important than choice of language (although obviously using PyPy over CPython is often going to help). Here one can solve the problem in O(log n) or even O(1) time, which are hundreds or thousands of times faster that the original code when N and K are at the upper end of the competition's limits.

Answer (score 1):

You can build up the result from the highest bit downwards. At each point, you can test if there's a pair of numbers both <= n with the given bits set.

You can observe that if `nr` is a given number, then `nr|(nr+1)` is the smallest number different from `nr` with at least the same bits set as `nr`.

```
def maxpair(n, k):
    result = 0
    for bit in xrange(63, -1, -1):
        nr = result | (1<<bit)
        if nr < k and (nr|(nr+1)) <= n:
            result = nr
    return result
```

This works in O(log n) time [if you generalize the code a little, replacing 64 with the number of bits in the result], which is fast enough even for ridiculously large n.

One can check correctness by comparing against a naive but obviously correct solution.

```
def maxpair_slow(n, k):
    best = 0
    for a in xrange(1, n+1):
        for b in xrange(a+1, n+1):
            if (a&b) < k:
                best = max(best, a&b)
    return best

for N in xrange(100):
    for K in xrange(2, N):
        m1 = maxpair(N, K)
        m2 = maxpair_slow(N, K)
        if m1 != m2:
            print N, K, m1, m2
```

There is also an O(1) solution, since the solution is always K-1, K-2 or K-3, and one needs only test those three possibilities:

```
def maxpair2(n, k):
    return next(i for i in (k-1,k-2,k-3) if i|(i+1)<=n)
```

Comment: I must have screwed up the implementation, but when I input this code it gives off wrong answers.

testCases = int(raw_input())
while testCases > 0:
    n_k = raw_input().split()
    n = int(n_k[0])
    k = int(n_k[1])
    max_pair = 0
    for bit in xrange(max_pair.bit_length(), -1, -1):
        nr = max_pair | (1<<bit)
        if nr < k and (nr|nr+1) <= n:
            max_pair = nr
            break
    print max_pair        
    testCases -= 1

Comment: You changed 64 to max_pair.bit_length(), but max_pair is zero at the time of evaluation. Try k.bit_length() or just leave 64 in.

Comment: Cool stuff! Do you have some proof for `K-1,K-2,K-3`-part or is it from empirical data?

Comment: Yes, I have a proof. (k-i) & ((k-i)|(k-i+1)) = k-i, so it's just a matter of checking that that ((k-i)|(k-i+1)) is less than or equal to n for at least one of i=1, 2, 3, and noting that (k-i), ((k-i)|(k-i+1)) are the two smallest numbers whose bitwise and is k-i.